# Derivative of $C_c^\infty$ function again in $C_c^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

my question is the following: Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, let $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. Does this imply that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ for $i=1,\dots, n$?

Comment: yes..........................................................................

Comment: That all derivatives exist and are continuous means that all partial derivatives exist and are continuous ...

Comment: If your function is zero outside of a compact set, then all derivatives are zero outside of that set as well. I think these comments give you a full answer now.

Comment: Look at [$f(x) = e^{-1/(1-x^2)} 1_{|x| < 1} \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)

Comment: Yes. I wanted to make sure. Thank you :).